# Microsoft graph api access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need a solution for accessing Microsoft graph api with a token which never expires for a multitenant application.

I am using frontend as react and backend as lambda function.

Actual requirement
**Need to connect Microsoft app (which will give access to graph api's) with project where same auth will be used by multiple users, same authentication should work until it revoked.**

Comment: What you meant by "token never expires"? You want to keep the token lifetime as never expire? Why you want want to do that way...

Comment: its not possible out of the box solution with token lifetime . however we have implement azure function with username and password when ever it calls first call to azure function and request token

Comment: I think you can use refresh token to get new access tokens when an access token is about to expire

Answer (score 1):

Take ***OAuth 2.0 auth code grant*** as an example.

Currently, [access token lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties-after-the-retirement) cannot be configured to be permanent.

Therefore,You can [Request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token)
and you can [Refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) when it expired.

Comment: @HARISHGOWDAK ...what does mean "same auth"？If you want to use the same token used by mutiple users,suppose that the token issuer is an administrator, the average user cannot use it.

Comment: ....same auth means, I need save the auth somewhere and I can re use in diffrent browser too